Search for text in a very large txt file (50+GB)
I have a hashes.txt file that stores strings and their compressed SHA-256 hash values. Each line in the file is formatted as follows:
<compressed_hash>:<original_string>
The compressed_hash is created by taking the 6th, 13th, 20th, and 27th characters of the full SHA-256 hash. For example, the string alon when hashed: 5a24f03a01d5b10cab6124f3c0e7086994ac9c869fc8e76e1463458f829fc864 would be stored as:
0db3:alon
I have a search.py script that works like this
For example, if the user inputs 5a24f03a01d5b10cab6124f3c0e7086994ac9c869fc8e76e1463458f829fc864 in search.py the script searches for its shortened form, 0db3 in hashes.txt.
If multiple matches are found, like:
0db3:alon

0db3:apple

The script rehashes the matches (alon, apple) to get their full SHA-256 hash, and if there is a match (eg. alon when fully hashed matches the user input (5a24f03a01d5b10cab6124f3c0e7086994ac9c869fc8e76e1463458f829fc864), the script prints the string (alon)
The problem with this script is that it, the search usually takes around 1 hour, and my hashes.txt is 54GB. Here is the search.py:
import hashlib
import mmap

def compress_hash(hash_value):
    return hash_value[6] + hash_value[13] + hash_value[20] + hash_value[27]

def search_compressed_hash(hash_input, compressed_file):
    compressed_input = compress_hash(hash_input)
    potential_matches = []
    
    with open(compressed_file, "r+b") as file:
        # Memory-map the file, size 0 means the whole file
        mmapped_file = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0)
        
        # Read through the memory-mapped file line by line
        for line in iter(mmapped_file.readline, b""):
            line = line.decode().strip()
            parts = line.split(":", 1)  # Split only on the first colon
            if len(parts) == 2:  # Ensure there are exactly two parts
                compressed_hash, string = parts
                if compressed_hash == compressed_input:
                    potential_matches.append(string)
        
        mmapped_file.close()
    
    return potential_matches

def verify_full_hash(potential_matches, hash_input):
    for string in potential_matches:
        if hashlib.sha256(string.encode()).hexdigest() == hash_input:
            return string
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        hash_input = input("Enter the hash (or type 'exit' to quit): ")
        if hash_input.lower() == 'exit':
            break
        
        potential_matches = search_compressed_hash(hash_input, "hashes.txt")
        found_string = verify_full_hash(potential_matches, hash_input)
        
        if found_string:
            print(f"Corresponding string: {found_string}")
        else:
            print("String not found for the given hash.")

And, if it helps, here's the hash.py script that actually generates the strings and hashes and puts them in hashes.txt
import hashlib
import sys
import time

`# Set the interval for saving progress (in seconds)
SAVE_INTERVAL = 60  # Save progress every minute
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000000  # Number of hashes to buffer before writing to file

def generate_hash(string):
    return hashlib.sha256(string.encode()).hexdigest()

def compress_hash(hash_value):
    return hash_value[6] + hash_value[13] + hash_value[20] + hash_value[27]

def write_hashes_to_file(start_length):
    buffer = []  # Buffer to store generated hashes
    last_save_time = time.time()  # Store the last save time
    
    for generated_string in generate_strings_and_hashes(start_length):
        full_hash = generate_hash(generated_string)
        compressed_hash = compress_hash(full_hash)
        buffer.append((compressed_hash, generated_string))
        
        if len(buffer) >= BUFFER_SIZE:
            save_buffer_to_file(buffer)
            buffer = []  # Clear the buffer after writing to file
        
        # Check if it's time to save progress
        if time.time() - last_save_time >= SAVE_INTERVAL:
            print("Saving progress...")
            save_buffer_to_file(buffer)  # Save any remaining hashes in buffer
            buffer = []  # Clear buffer after saving
            last_save_time = time.time()
    
    # Save any remaining hashes in buffer
    if buffer:
        save_buffer_to_file(buffer)

def save_buffer_to_file(buffer):
    with open("hashes.txt", "a") as file_hashes:
        file_hashes.writelines(f"{compressed_hash}:{generated_string}\n" for compressed_hash, generated_string in buffer)

def generate_strings_and_hashes(start_length):
    for length in range(start_length, sys.maxsize):  # Use sys.maxsize to simulate infinity
        current_string = [' '] * length  # Initialize with spaces
        while True:
            yield ''.join(current_string)
            if current_string == ['z'] * length:  # Stop when all characters reach 'z'
                break
            current_string = increment_string(current_string)

def increment_string(string_list):
    index = len(string_list) - 1
    
    while index >= 0:
        if string_list[index] == 'z':
            string_list[index] = ' '
            index -= 1
        else:
            string_list[index] = chr(ord(string_list[index]) + 1)
            break
    
    if index < 0:
        string_list.insert(0, ' ')
    
    return string_list

def load_progress():
    # You may not need this function anymore
    return 1  # Just return a default value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_hashes_to_file(load_progress())`

My OS is Windows 10.

it appears that this performs a linear search. You should store your hashes in sorted order, get a fixed linesize, so you can use dichotomic search on the big file.

The strings in hashes.txt are sorted alphabetically, here's just an example from the last lines;
46f6: t8j9
2e1e: t8j:

You only have 65536 unique search keys. Why not just make 65536 files? You could use 256 directories with 256 files each to keep it manageable.
Then you can entirely eliminate all of the lookup process. Bonus: your files are smaller because you don’t need to store the key at all.
You’ll have to do some one-time processing to split your big hash file into smaller files, of course, but your lookups should be effectively instant.

That's a great idea, i'll try to implement it
